# Transform a HTML in CSV Using Python and Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, csv

I have a doubt, I'm Working in a program that need do take data from website, but that site doesn't have any API.

So I'm thinking to combine JavaScript and Python.

I'm using JavaScript to transform HTML in this data:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body>BLUE - Amil Ltda14/07/2020;;102636;Name censured;213113;10101039;1;Única;20/09/2020;102636;HCRIANÇASJ;83,00; <br>BLUE18 - Amil Ltda21/07/2020;;102636;Name Censured Again;213029;10101039;1;Única;20/09/2020;102636;HCRI;83,00;
```

But python interprets like one string and I need to convert in `csv` or `json` like format.

I'm trying to use `.replace (<br>,//n)` but it didn't work.

Plus, I need to delete the following section:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body>BLUE - Amil Ltda14/07/2020
```

Comment: Use an HTML scraping tool like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const str = `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body>BLUE - Amil Ltda14/07/2020;;102636;Name censured;213113;10101039;1;Única;20/09/2020;102636;HCRIANÇASJ;83,00; <br>BLUE18 - Amil Ltda21/07/2020;;102636;Name Censured Again;213029;10101039;1;Única;20/09/2020;102636;HCRI;83,00;`;
const lines = str.split(/<br>/gs);
for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    lines[i] = lines[i].replace(/(.*)BLUE\d*\s-\sAmil\sLtda\d+\/\d+\/\d+;;/, '');
}
console.log(lines);
```